# Where to put an adverb?

Tags: adverb-position

Can somebody say where I should put the adverb in this phrase:                                "I’m going to thoroughly teach you a lesson." or "I’m going to teach you a lesson thoroughly." And which adverb is better: "thoroughly" or "properly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the adverb any way, and it'll still be grammatically correct.

Also, here are the meanings of the adverb `thoroughly`. This is from [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20thoroughly):

> 1. in a thorough manner; in depth; minutely; closely.
> 2. very much; greatly.

This is the meaning of `thoroughly` from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thoroughly). The last one is probably not the best definition of `thoroughly` in your example:

> 1. executed without negligence or omissions.
> 2. complete; perfect; utter.
> 3. extremely attentive to accuracy and detail; painstaking.
> 4. having full command or mastery of an art, talent, etc.;

And finally, `thoroughly` from [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thoroughly):

> 1. Exhaustively complete: a thorough search.
> 2. Painstakingly accurate or careful: thorough research.
> 3. Absolute; utter: a thorough pleasure.

And on the other hand, we have the adverb `properly` according to [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20properly). The second one is a definition for British English:

> 1. correctly or satisfactorily.
> 2. thoroughly; completely.

Here is `properly` from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/properly):

> 1. thoroughly; completely.

And last but not least, here is `properly` from [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/properly), which basically is saying it is a synonym of the other adverb `thoroughly`:

> 1. Thoroughly

Comment: Peanut, thank you. So you think it's way better to put here "properly", right? Maybe I can make up a phrase like this: "I'm going to teach you a good lesson."?

Comment: Yes, I do believe `properly` is better. Also, you can do that.